# Hide button on toggle

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I have a simple request but I have a a toggle button which basically hides a div off screen to the left which works fine. The button is on the inside of the div so when it hides the div you are unable to open it again because the button is off the screen. Now I have created a new button to open it but I only want it to show once the div has been hidden, so its like a tab just showing to open the div again.

```
// Slider info box toggle
function toggleDivs() {

var $inner = $("#slideToggle");

    if ($inner.position().left == 0) {
        $inner.animate({
            left: "-840px"
        });
    }
    else {
        $inner.animate({
            left: "0px"
        });
    }
    }

    $(".sliderClose").bind("click", function() {
        toggleDivs();
    }); 

    $(".sliderOpen").bind("click", function() {
        toggleDivs();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the button you want to hide/show has class `.slideOpen` then

```
function toggleDivs() {

var $inner = $("#slideToggle");

    if ($inner.position().left == 0) {
        $inner.animate({
            left: "-840px"
        });
       $(".sliderOpen").fadeIn();
    }
    else {
        $inner.animate({
            left: "0px"
        });
       $(".sliderOpen").fadeOut();
    }
    }

    $(".sliderClose").bind("click", function() {
        toggleDivs();
    }); 

    $(".sliderOpen").bind("click", function() {
        toggleDivs();
    });
```

Comment: Well, I need the slideOpen to be hidden and when the slideClose button is clicked for the slideOpen button to appear.

Comment: Yes that's what my code will do. All you need to do is just add style display:none; to .sliderOpen so that its hidden in the starting..

Comment: It doesn't appear to be working, the open button does not appear? I have set it to display: none in the css.

Comment: I hope that you have added $(".sliderOpen").fadeIn(); and $(".sliderOpen").fadeOut(); in the function definition.

Comment: How do you mean? I tried the code you posted above :)

Comment: Please refer the function I have posted above in my answer. I have added two lines in the if...else condition. Can you please post a jsfiddle.

Comment: I added the exact code you provided and also added display none to in the css